# ifelse statement return value from same df row

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm not sure why this is so difficult, but I simply want to return the data in rowX,colB when rowX,colA is > 70.

```
df

colA    colB 
80      6
75      7
60      5
66      4

vector <- ifelse(df$colA > 70, paste0('above 70', df$colB), 'below 70')
```

The result is a vector with 'below 70' if below 70 and NA if above 70, but why? Even if the ifelse statement doesn't understand the row for df$colB it should never return NA as `paste0('above 70', df$colB)` is actually a dataframe. Is the ifelse statement blind to the row number it's evaluating outside of the first conditional statement?

Comment: is `df` of class `data.frame`? I tried applying your code to a dataframe that matches your example and it returns `"above 706" "above 707" "below 70"  "below 70" `

Comment: Damn it was behaving correctly, I just had NAs in my data. Thank you so much! At least I'm not going crazy